# node.js: sending a number with connection initiate

Tags: node.js

sorry, but i have a problem. I have progged a community. I want ro realize a 1:1-Chat in this community.

If a user logs in at the community, he's initiate a connection in the login.php-File:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
```

Now the question: can i send the userid with this line? 
Because i want to store a pair of numbers in my sql-DB on the chatserver: the connection id and the id of the communitymember. That's because i have to inform a communitymember in chat if his chatpartner is logout and unreachable.

Very Thanks!!! And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

On the client, just pass the user id as a query string.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080?user=123');
```

On the server, you will probably want to handle the data in a `connection` handler. To do this, you have to add an `authorization` handler, and save the data into the `handshakeData` object. You can then access it on `socket.handshake`.

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback)
{
    handshakeData.userId = handshakeData.query.user;
    callback(null, true);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log(socket.id, ' => ', socket.handshake.userId);
}
```